# printing very large floating point numbers

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, standards, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <float.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%f\n", FLT_MAX);
}
```

Output from GNU:

```
340282346638528859811704183484516925440.000000
```

Output from Visual Studio:

```
340282346638528860000000000000000000000.000000
```

Do the C and C++ standards allow both results? Or do they mandate a specific result?

Note that `FLT_MAX = 2^128-2^104 = 340282346638528859811704183484516925440`.

Comment: The C and C++ standards don't even mandate a specific floating-point representation. So I'm tempted to think that they can't mandate a specific result.

Comment: @Mysticial Well, they might still generally mandate that "the exact value that is represented must be printed out" or something to that extent.

Comment: And Unix pwns Windows. Once again.

Comment: @H2CO3, how do you conclude that GNU is better than Windows? I prefer the Microsoft result as it correctly implies that the resolution is limited.

Comment: Check out my two articles http://www.exploringbinary.com/print-precision-of-dyadic-fractions-varies-by-language/ and http://www.exploringbinary.com/print-precision-of-floating-point-integers-varies-too/ . You'll see how the number of digits varies by language and implementation.

Comment: Note that Windows prints the **shortest** decimal representation that will reconstruct the same **double** while gnu libc prints the **exact** decimal representation of internal representation mantissa*2^exponent. Both print too many digits for a single precision float IMHO, but how to not promote a float to double in C? For a REPL language, the shortest representation has more value, you want to print what you typed. For a general purpose language, a good library should offer the 2 possibilities.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the relevant part of the C99 standard is the "Recommended practice" from 7.19.6.1 p.13:

> For `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, and `G` conversions, if the number of significant decimal digits is at most
>   `DECIMAL_DIG`, then the result should be correctly rounded. If the number of
>   significant decimal digits is more than `DECIMAL_DIG` but the source value is exactly
>   representable with `DECIMAL_DIG` digits, then the result should be an exact
>   representation with trailing zeros. Otherwise, the source value is bounded by two
>   adjacent decimal strings *L* < *U*, both having `DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits; the value
>   of the resultant decimal string *D* should satisfy *L* <= *D* <= *U*, with the extra stipulation that
>   the error should have a correct sign for the current rounding direction.

My impression is that this allows some leeway in what may be printed in this case; so my conclusion is that both VS and GCC are compliant here.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: none has more precision. GNU cheats you to think it has, but it's result is even worse than MSVC's. Floating point represents *intervals*, not numbers. So 340282346638528859811704183484516925440, 340282346638528859811704183484516925450, and 340282346638528860000000000000000000000 are all the same floating point value (for 64-bit ieee). [A better floating point formatting rountine is actually the one that gives you the shortest possible representation](http://florian.loitsch.com/publications/dtoa-pldi2010.pdf).

Comment: @ybungalobill: Floating point does not represent intervals. It represents diadic rationals which may be exact or results of rounding depending on your usage. Doing interval arithmetic with floating point is actually *very difficult* (and either expands the intervals rapidly or requires constant changing of rounding direction and an implementation that respects rounding modes).

Comment: @FredOverflow: The GNU result is the correct value, but both seem to conform to both the requirements and recommended practice in the standard.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Regarding your link, for some purposes (such as serialization), choosing the shortest representation that will survive the round trip conversion may be optimal, but this is very application-specific. If there's a chance that rounding mode will be different when printing and scanning the decimal value, printing the exact value is the only robust approach. And for serialization, if you're using decimal floats and not hex floats or something else more efficient, you're doing something really wrong...

Comment: @R.: representing intervals != interval arithmetic. It represents intervals, but the arithmetic is defined as regular arithmetic on a representative in the said interval. It's not the same as interval arithmetic, but then again it's irrelevant to the question. Please read some literature. If you didn't like the linked article, you may like [this one](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse590p/590k_02au/print-fp.pdf), or refer to Knuth.

Comment: @R.: rounding mode has nothing to do with this. The linked articles describe algorithms that produce representations that will be read correctly regardless of the rounding mode on the other side. It has to do with *precision*. Try printing `1e-20` with 20 digits of precision. MSVC prints 9.9999999999999995e-021 and GCC prints 9.9999999999999994515e-21, their behavior is just misleading, because the last `5` or `4515` are [insignificant digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).

Comment: They are not insignificant digits. The problem is that the value "1e-20" already got rounded. The GNU libc (not GCC; GCC is a compiler and irrelevant to `printf` behavior) version prints the exact value of floating point expression. The last digits may be meaningless to *you* if you meant the value to represent the number 1e-20, but `printf` has no way of knowing that you intended as an approximation of 1e-20 and not the exact value of the floating point expression. The MSVCRT behavior is not beneficial in any way; it's just lazy.

Comment: @R.. I agree except in one point. Producing the shortest round-tripping representation is not lazy. It's more work than producing just a _sufficiently long_ (for roundtripping) representation.

Comment: @Daniel: MSVCRT is not attempting to produce the shortest round-tripping representation; as far as I can tell, that would not conform to the recommended practice. The length is already governed by `DECIMAL_DIG`. Otherwise, I agree.

Comment: @R.: Arguing that they 'aren't insignificant' is pointless, since it's well defined mathematical concept: if you change a digit and it doesn't change the number when it's read again, then it's insignificant. And 'the exact value of float' doesn't have a real world use just as 'counting the number of characters in a Unicode string', and as all other crap that people invent just to justify the way they expect something to work. You don't know whether rounding happened. From floating point math point of view,

Comment: all real numbers that round to the said floating point value are equivalent for external representation. 
@Daniel: Theoretically it's more work. Yet, my implementation of printf based on grisu is 2.5 times faster than MSVC's. So don't feed me this either.

Comment: As specified by the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic, 754-2008, floating-point data represents only specific numbers (and NaNs), not intervals. Per section 3.3, the data represented are +0; -0; numbers of the form (-1)**s * b**e * m, where s is 0 or 1, and b, e, and m are a suitable base, exponent, and significand for the specific floating-point type; +infinity, -infinity, quiet NaN, and signaling Nan. The results of floating-point operations are dictated by the individual numbers represented by operands, not by the intervals around them.

Answer (score 1):

Both are allowed by the C standard (C++ just inports the C standard)

From a [draft version](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) in section 5.2.4.2.2 part 10

> The values given in the following list shall be replaced by constant expressions with
>   implementation-deﬁned values that are greater than or equal to those shown:
>    — maximum representable ﬁnite ﬂoating-point number, (1 − b −p)b emax

```
FLT_MAX 1E+37
```

and visual C++ 2012 has

```
#define FLT_MAX         3.402823466e+38F        /* max value */
```

Comment: In practice, the value of `FLT_MAX` will be the same on any platform that uses IEEE-754 floating-point.  So that's not the issue here.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:  Okay, maybe "flawed" is too strong.  It is invoking undefined results.

Answer (score 0):

The code itself is flawed where it uses `%f` for a value larger than significance held in a `float` or `double`.  By doing so you are asking to see "behind the curtain" as to the meaningless guard bits or other floating point noise generated in the conversion to decimal.

Clearly you should not expect any consistency in the metal filings generated after making an engine at Honda versus at Toyota.  Nevermind any sensible expectation of such consistency.

The proper way to display such numbers is by using one of the "scientific" formats such as `%g` provided precision is not over-specified.  On IEEE-754 implementations, 7 decimal figures are significant for `float`, 15-16 for `double`, about 19 for `long double`, and 34 for `__float128`.  So, for the example you have given, `%.15g` would be proper, assuming it is on a IEEE-754 implementation.

Comment: Using `%f` is not "flawed".  The question is asking what the standard allows "behind the curtains".

Comment: @OliCharlesworth:  Okay, maybe "flawed" is too strong.  It is invoking undefined results.